# PHP image generator/handler

Tags: php, image-manipulation, httphandler

I'd like to create a PHP image generator that takes several query string parameters and generates an image on the fly. I've done this before in ASP.NET via a handler but now I'd like to in PHP. For example, I'd like a call to `image.php?img1=foo.jpg&img2=bar.jpg` to render the concatenation of `foo.jpg` horizontally next to `bar.jpg`. Later on I'll do some mod_rewrite to make it something like `foo_bar.jpg` but that's not my concern. Are there any samples out there that do what I want or any code snippets to examine? This is actually more of a learning experience than a necessary step to build something.

Here's a sample application of it:

```
image.php?d=14&m=jan&y=2010
```

Would really be the graphic concatenation of `14.jpg` + `jan.jpg` + `2010.jpg`

And after mod_rewite it could be used like:

```
14_jan_2010.jpg
```

Comment: I recommend checking out Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library can certainly do this. You can work out how large the image needs to be, create a blank one and then use [`imagecopymerge()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) to copy the three images into it.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with it. I can't even take an image 1.jpg of size 10x10 and combine it with another image, 2.jpg of size 10x10 to make a new image of size 20x10! Do you have any specific code that actually does something as simple as that?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some sample code if it helps.

*http://www.psych0tik.net/images/sig.phps* ::EDIT LINK IS BROKEN. I'll fix it shortly.

It's very simple (and doesn't do exactly what you want) but should be able to fulfill your needs with some minor hackery.